# Postgres 9.3 Group By and Count Function

Tags: database, postgresql, count, group-by

I'm slightly new to databases but I've got some experience on MySQL but now I'm making an app which uses Postgres and I'm confuse how queries works with postgres or the structure is slightly different to MySQL. And I really don't know where to start. So I have a table

```
qa_forms
->id
->agent_id
->verified_status
```

The column `verified_status` can have a value of `Passed, Passed-Approved, Passed-With Changes, Passed-Unverified, Pending, Reject A, Reject B, Reject C` What I want to do is count the total number of each `Passed, Passed-Approved, Passed-With Changes, Passed-Unverified, Pending, Reject A, Reject B, Reject C` per `agent_id` so it is `GROUP BY agent_id` I guess. I have Postgres 9.3. This is the report should look like:

[image]

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen managed to get some query work. see my answer below, any better suggestion is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and seems working fine. Any better answer is appreciated.

```
`SELECT agent_id, 
COUNT(verified_status = 'Passed' OR NULL) AS passed, 
COUNT(verified_status = 'Passed-Approved' OR NULL) AS passed_approved,
COUNT(verified_status = 'Passed-With Changes' OR NULL) AS passed_changes,
COUNT(verified_status = 'Passed-Unverified' OR NULL) AS passed_unverified,
COUNT(verified_status = 'Pending' OR NULL) AS pending,
COUNT(verified_status = 'Reject A' OR NULL) AS reject_a,
COUNT(verified_status = 'Reject B' OR NULL) AS reject_b,
COUNT(verified_status = 'Reject C' OR NULL) AS reject_c
FROM qa_forms 
GROUP BY agent_id;`
```